# Как сделать аутентификацию через React-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, redux, token, react-router-dom

**Как выполнить аутентификацию пользователя через react-router-dom?**

---

При аутентификации получаю токен и записываю его в *localStorage* (*и в redux store*) 
Когда пользователь загружает приложение проверяю на существование этого поля 
и если оно существует, должен показать ему страницу **UsersList**.

В моем случае, приложение сначала говорит что токена нет, потом проводит проверку, 
 но **redirect** на форму авторизации уже произошел (**код компонента ниже**). 
Подскажите как сделать аутентификацию

> P.S. если нужно дополнить вопрос, напишите комментарии дополню

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import {checkOnAuth} from "../store/actions";
import {
    Auth, UsersList, Error
} from "../pages";


const Routers = ({ token, checkOnAuth }) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        checkOnAuth();
    }, []);

    const isAuthenticated = !!token;
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    render={() => (
                        isAuthenticated
                            ? <UsersList />
                            : <Redirect to="/auth" />
                        )}
                    exact
                />
                <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} exact />
                <Route component={Error} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

let mapStateToProps = state => ({token: state.auth.token});
let mapDispatchToProps = { checkOnAuth };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Routers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `Redirect` сразу `Auth`

Comment: Пробовал, работает, но мигает (сначала 1 компонент прогружается <Auth />, потом второй <UsersList />)

Comment: мигает -- это уже лучше, т. е. на секунду Auth кажет, а потом  UsersList.

Comment: > приложение сначала говорит что токена нет, потом проводит проверку
[variant 1] если сделать 3 состояния есть/нету/пока-не-знаю
[variant 2] положить правильное состояние в сторе сразу в ините

Comment: Я правильно понял, что token в пропах из сторе, а checkOnAuth кладет в сторе?

Comment: Попробую вечером, возможно сработает, еще можно попробовать дожидаться проверки, а потом показывать страницу

Comment: > "дожидаться проверки, а потом показывать страницу ". Это я и имел ввиду с состоянием "пока-не-знаю"